# Powershell Naming shortcut

Tags: powershell

```
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$desktop = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut($sourceDir+"\ShortcutName.lnk")
$lnk.TargetPath = "$destination"
$lnk.Save()
```

I have a script in PowerShell that at the very end creates a shortcut in the $sourceDir directory which is currently being named "ShortcutName.lnk". I need to pass a variable which will be used as the name I've tried creating one called $test which is equal to the $item.FullName although I can't seem to append that to the CreateShortcut param $sourceDir+"\ShortcutName.lnk".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut((Join-Path $sourceDir "ShortcutName.lnk"))
```

Should work. Join-Path will take care of adding slashes as needed.

If you want to use your existing file object:

```
$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut((Join-Path $sourceDir ([io.path]::ChangeExtension($item.name, "lnk"))))
```

Comment: I've just added this to my code however I got "The shortcut pathname must end with .lnk or .url" error. How would I append .lnk to this?

Comment: Guess you have kept "$test" when copy-pasting?

Comment: @Android Magic Fixed the answer

Comment: @whatever That's it! Thanks very much mate! :)